# How can I use nscala_time inside spark-shell?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nscala-time

I'm trying to test some code out in the spark-shell and I need to set some time fields. We're using `nscala_time` for DateTime functionality. When I run

```
$ scala -cp `ls -1 | tr "\\n" ":"`
```

from the directory with my staged jars, everything works fine and I can run

```
scala> import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

scala> val current = DateTime.now
current: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-04-23T10:44:35.984-07:00
```

however when I try the same thing with `spark-shell` 1.3.0

```
$ spark-shell -cp `ls -1 | tr "\\n" ":"
```

I end up with errors doing the same thing as in the `scala` console

```
scala> import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._

scala> val current = DateTime.now
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.$conforms()Lscala/Predef$$less$colon$less;
    at com.github.nscala_time.time.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits$class.ReadableInstantOrdering(Implicits.scala:64)
    at com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports$.ReadableInstantOrdering(Imports.scala:20)
    at com.github.nscala_time.time.OrderingImplicits$class.$init$(Implicits.scala:56)
    at com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports$.<init>(Imports.scala:20)
    at com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports$.<clinit>(Imports.scala)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:22)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:39)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:41)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:43)
    at <init>(<console>:45)
    at .<init>(<console>:49)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Anyone have any ideas why I can't use nscala_time in spark-shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use spark 1.3.0 and it has much more better error output. It tells me that:

> scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeError: bad symbolic reference. A
>   signature in BuilderImplicits.class refers to term time in value
>   org.joda which is not available.

So, i downloaded missing org.joda [jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time/2.7) and run spark with it:

```
~  spark-shell --jars nscala-time_2.10-0.2.0.jar,joda-time-2.7.jar
...

scala> import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._
scala> val current = DateTime.now
current: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2015-04-23T22:35:50.344+03:00
```

The other my guess is that you should try to run your code in paste mode (`scala>:paste`). The stack trace looks pretty close to the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1199). Maybe the problem is in spark-shell itself.

Comment: I tried again with those two jars and received the same error. The only difference now is the versions 2.11-2.0 of nscala and 2.3 of joda time. I'll try messing with the versions.

Comment: And writing your code in paste mode doesn't help either?

Comment: same in :paste. Interesting thing with :paste too is that if I do the import in there it doesn't get listed in :imports after it's interpreted.

Comment: Sure enough it was a version issue. I grabbed nscala-time_2.10-1.8.0 and that works. Odd thing is that this is ONLY a problem with spark-shell. It works fine everywhere else.

Comment: spark-shell --jars nscala-time_2.10-0.2.0.jar,joda-time-2.7.jar,  this works.